# Finding common values across rows of dataframe with a restriction based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

Given example dataframe below, how to find users in the same location who have the same interest? The data is-

```
userid   interest    location
 1       [A, B]          Z
 2       [A, C, B]       Y
 3       [B, D]          Z
 4       [A, C]          Y
 5       [A, B, D]       Z
```

The output should be-

```
userid    relativeid  common interest  location
  1          3           [B]              Z
  1          5           [A, B]           Z
  2          4           [A,C]            Y
```

So far, I created separate dataframes for each location like the one below-

```
userid   interest    location
 1       [A, B]          Z
 3       [B, D]          Z
 5       [A, B, D]       Z
```

the code-

```
dictionary = df.set_index('userid')['interest'].map(set).to_dict()
dictionary

out = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df.userid, 2)), columns=['userid', 'relative_id']) 
out['common_interest'] = [list(dictionary[x] & dictionary[y]) for x, y in out.values]
out
```

but this gives me output without the location column.

```
userid    relativeid  common interest 
  1          3           [B]              
  1          5           [A, B]
```

Questions:
1) how to modify this code to get the location column in output?
2) Is there a way to do this without splitting the original data frame into multiple data frames based on location?

Comment: 3 and 5 have the common B

Comment: @Wen-Ben yes 3 and 5 would have common B

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "common interest in the same location"?  Are you only interested in comparing users who have the same location value?  And is there a 1:1 relationship between userid and location?  Because if it's 1:1, and you are not comparing users 1 and 2 to each other for example (users in different locations), you should just be able to merge the location column onto your final dataframe by userid.

Comment: @AlexK I have multiple users, their interests(stored in lists) and their locations (countries where they reside). for example I have 10 users in total, 5 are from location X, 3 from location Y and 2 from location Z, I want to write a python program that figures out users in locations X, Y and Z and then compares every user with every other user in the same location to find out their common interests. my code creates a new df for every new location and clubs people with same location together in that df. I want to do this without creating a new df for every new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution.  I noted the added code.  There is just an extra dictionary created to keep location information for each userid, a function that removes combinations of users if they don't share the same location, and a line at the end that uses that same location dictionary to create location column on the final dataframe.

```
import itertools

users_df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,2,3,4,5],'interest':[['A','B'],['A','C','B'],['B','D'],['A','C'],['A','B','D']],
                        'location':['Z','Y','Z','Y','Z']})

#new code: location dictionary
loc_dict = users_df.set_index('userid')['location'].to_dict()

#new code: function that removes userid combinations when locations are different
def restrict_users(all_combs):
    return [comb for comb in all_combs if loc_dict[comb[0]] == loc_dict[comb[1]]]

dictionary = users_df.set_index('userid')['interest'].map(set).to_dict()

#new function applied below
out = pd.DataFrame(restrict_users(list(itertools.combinations(users_df.userid, 2))), columns=['userid', 'relative_id']) 
out['common_interest'] = [list(dictionary[x] & dictionary[y]) for x, y in out.values]
#location column added to the dataframe
out['location'] = out['userid'].map(loc_dict)

out
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, without having to create sub data frames. It looks kinda heavy though. Credits go to @AlexK for the init of the frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,2,3,4,5],'interest':[['A','B'],['A','C','B'],['B','D'],['A','C'],['A','B','D']],
                        'location':['Z','Y','Z','Y','Z']})
# Builds a dictionary of location as key and a list of index of users in df as value
idxlocation = df.groupby('location').apply(lambda x: x.index.values).to_dict()

new_frame = []
for k, v  in idxlocation.items():
    for i in itertools.combinations(v, 2):
        userid = df.loc[i[0], 'userid']
        relativeid = df.loc[i[1], 'userid']
        new_frame.append((userid, relativeid, [j for j in set(df.loc[i[0], 'interest']).intersection(set(df.loc[i[1], 'interest']))], k))

out = pd.DataFrame(new_frame)
out.columns = ['userid', 'relative_id', 'common_interest', 'location']

>>>out
   userid  relative_id common_interest location
0       2            4          [A, C]        Y
1       1            3             [B]        Z
2       1            5          [A, B]        Z
3       3            5          [D, B]        Z
```